# Error while creating Singleton using interface with static property in C# 8.0

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

A problem occurred while creating a singleton using an interface with static properties.

```
public interface ISingleton<T> where T : new()
{
    static T instnace { get; set; }
    static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            instnace ??= new T();
            return instnace;
        }
    }
}

public class Manager : ISingleton<Manager>
{
}

// TODO : Error!
var manager = Manager.Instance;
```

The problem is that I can't find the `Instance` property defined in that interface
Why can't I find that property?

Comment: ?instnace?  Even if the misspelling was deliberate - that's definitely a Bad Practice!  Whatever you're trying to do is "weird".  If you want a "Singleton" (depending on your specific use case), you might want to declare a class (or an interface) with a static *METHOD* (that returns an  object instance).  Or if DI is applicable, register a "service" with AddSingleton: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad practice so I would not use an interface like that but here is how it can be used.

```cs
public interface ISingleton<T> where T : new()
{
    static T Instance { get; } = new T();
}

public class Manager : ISingleton<Manager>
{
}

// then later
var manager = ISingleton<Manager>.Instance;
```

Or another solution could be something like this:

```cs
// this is an implementation similar to EmptyArray<T> internal BCL type.

public static class Singleton<T> where T : new()
{
    public static readonly T Instance = new T();
}

// then you can access it this way
var manager = Singleton<Manager>.Instance;

// Note: in this case the T type does not have to implement any specific interface.
```

Anyway, I suggest considering using a DI framework instead of manually implementing the singleton pattern.

Comment: thank you! I guess I'm still a beginner...

Answer (score 1):

You call statics on the interface , not on the implementing class

```
 var manager = ISingleton<Manager>.Instance;
```

Comment: @ChoiMinGyu - it was new to me - I had to go digging, MS docs truly suck on the new interface features